# C# Datetime is increasing by 3 hours

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime, timezone

My dates are being stored in sql server.

Windows server region and timezone are correct, but when I see the date in database it's increased by 3 hours, I think it is comming from some server configuration that is overriding, but don't know where else to look.

When I send date from local project to production database, it saves correctly, but when I use production website it doesn't.

Where else should I check to solve this?

Comment: Either always save times as UTC or use `datetimeoffset`, in code and in the database. What you describe means different applications are using different timezones to save *local* times to the database

Comment: the timezone and region is the same in local application computer and on the server computer, and database is the same too.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - yes sounds like a mix of local and UTC format date storage and retrieval.

Comment: @RaphaelRibeiro and all of them are different. The only way to avoid this is to either use UTC everywhere, or explicitly include the offset by using the `datetimeinfo` type in the database and `DateTimeInfo` in the application

Comment: I know this is the best approach but it wasn't happening so something has changed and for now I just want things to get back to working as they were.

I dont know if it comes from some windows update or other thing, but it wasn't happening.

Comment: @RaphaelRibeiro you'll have to find that "something" then. The timezone in one of the machines changed. Perhaps you moved to a cloud server whose timezone is UTC. Perhaps an application was changed to save dates as UTC. Since Brazil is UTC-3 I suspect that some application is now working at UTC

Comment: `from some windows update` no, it comes from an explicit administration or developer change. `when I use production website it doesn't.` what's the timezone in the *web application*?

Comment: SQL server won't change the date time stored with regard to time zone. A stored procedure may, applications writing date time to the database may and applications used to retrieve and display  the date time may also. How are you viewing the date time stored in the database?

Comment: thats the problem, I dont know where else to check, I already checked that local and production server's timezone and region are correct.

Comment: @ChrisBD sql server management studio

Comment: So let's start diagnosing it.. Where is the data going wrong? On the way into the DB or on the way out of it? Use SSMS on the server to look at the table, insert a record, select it.. Is that OK, now use SSMS on your local machine or the web server machine to do the same, then use your code. Something, somewhere is getting this wrong and there are only two paths you really have to verify: the input and the output

Comment: You already said the production web app saves UTC dates instead of local. What's the timezone on that web server? What are the web app's configuration settings? Does *the web app code* attempt to "fix" the timezone? Does it change the DateTime Kind to Local or UTC?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos it's (UTC-03:00) Brasília

Comment: Do the dates come from user input? Perhaps the *browser* is at UTC? Or the form posts UTC dates back to the controller?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I am using the same browser for both local and production.

Comment: @CaiusJard database does not change the dates it receives, I already checked this, the production code is sending data with plus 3 hours.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos not from user, it's set in back end as creation date column.

Comment: Hold on - the local time zone is UTC-3? In which case data time stored as UTC will appear 3 hours ahead of local time.. So it's not being converted back to local time on retrieval.

Comment: Could your SQL have been using GETDATE() to set the creation time and now is using GETUTCDATE()?

Comment: @ChrisBD its not saving as UTC, its using normal DateTime.Now in C#, and sending it to database, database does not apply this +3, I already check this by sending from my local application to production database, this way it saves correctly, only adds +3 when I use production application.

Comment: @RaphaelRibeiro and since Brazil time is UTC -3, and the saved times are 3 hours later than Brazil time, it means the actual saved values are in UTC. This means the web server is in UTC. UTC isn't a different date type. If `DateTime.Now` returns UTC time, it means the server's local timezone offset is 0

Comment: Your production application is running on a server that is using  a GMT time source.

Comment: @ChrisBD there's no `GMT time source`. Perhaps you mean that the system timezone is GMT?

Comment: Sorry showing my age by mixing GMT with more modern UTC terminology. I think that the OP stated that the system time zone is correct. I've seen issues when a server was switched to using a time source taken from a GPS receiver, which gave UTC and offset for location separately. In any case as the application code is storing local time, the local time for the server is UTC. This illustrates why we should use UTC all the way through and ask users what time zones they are in for conversion on display to local time.

Comment: The devops sent me pictures from timezone and region from application server, and it's correct =(

Comment: I don't really think you answered my question. You need to look at your data flow closely. A date is generated somewhere and makes its way through your system until it hits your DB. Later it is pulled back out again and makes its way through until it hits e.g. a webpage. At some point in this process something happens that seems to be a timezone misinterpretation, given that your server is in -3 and your complaint is that the time is 3 hours wrong. Follow the trail; examine the date at every step and find the place where it goes wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in some machines of the load balance, there are several machines created from an image, the original was right but the copies were not, if I tried many times to save the registry, then I happened to be redirected to the machine with the correct configuration and then the record was saved with the correct date.

I just asked devops to correct the settings on the other machines.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the codebase running your production portal.

Use Datetime as utc and cater for it accordingly. Or add DatetimeOffset and calculate the difference when needed.

If you still have the luxury of refactoring, I advise you to take a little dive into the Dates and time handling, get a solid understanding of it, then code accordingly, so it doesn't fire back on you in later stages or usages.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get advantage of your local machine timezone you can use myDateTime.ToUniversalTime() to get the UTC time from your local time or myDateTime.ToLocalTime() to convert the UTC time to the local machine's time.

```
// convert UTC time from the database to the machine's time
DateTime databaseUtcTime = new DateTime(2011,6,5,10,15,00);
var localTime = databaseUtcTime.ToLocalTime();

// convert local time to UTC for database save
var databaseUtcTime = localTime.ToUniversalTime();
```

If you need to convert time from/to other timezones, you may use TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime() or TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc().

```
// convert UTC time from the database to japanese time
DateTime databaseUtcTime = new DateTime(2011,6,5,10,15,00);
var japaneseTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Tokyo Standard Time");
var japaneseTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(databaseUtcTime, japaneseTimeZone);

// convert japanese time to UTC for database save
var databaseUtcTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(japaneseTime, japaneseTimeZone);
```

Comment: I was missing local time with UTC. Used this UTC all around.